# Change into textbox into date format by using webpart C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

my code is like this

```
protected void SubmitbuttonID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList lst = web.Lists["PositionChangeForm"];
            SPListItem lstItem = lst.Items.Add();

            lstItem["Modified"] = ModifiedDate.Text;
            lstItem["Created"] = CreatedDate.Text;

            lstItem.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptiontextbox.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        ModifiedDate(textbox)

        CreatedDate(textbox)
    }
}
```

When I fill the form in `SharePoint` its showing following error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I know this error is coming because of `SharePoint` list validation. I have to convert those textbox into date and time format.

Hope this is understandable and I completely beginner. Please help me if you any idea about it.

Comment: `I know this error is coming because of SharePoint list validation` - your question should probably focus around that, then :). You should probably rename your question to something like 'How to change/find SharePoint date format', and simply focusing on getting a date to validate. You'd also probably want to show us the string you're trying to parse - the rest of the post isn't really relevant to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your input string into Datetime.

Try this :

```
 DateTime modifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ModifiedDate.Text);
 DateTime createdDate = Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate.Text);

 lstItem["Modified"] = modifiedDate ;
 lstItem["Created"] = createdDate ;
 lstItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't see the datestring you want to submit i can only say that dates /datetimes in SharePoint should be in a specific format.

Using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx which takes a datetime as parameter will return you string in the correct format which will be accepted by SharePoint